# How to return a mapping data in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I have a problem like this. I am very new to ethereum stuff. I have built a smart contract like this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract TrafficFine{
    struct Officer {
        string firstName ;
        string lastName;
        address account;
    }

    address public manager;
    uint public numberOfOffiers;

    mapping(address=>Officer) public officers;

    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);      
        _;
    }

    constructor () public{
        manager = msg.sender;
        //fineAmount =0;
    }

    function addOfficer(string firstName,string lastName,address officer) public  restricted{

        require(officer!=officers[officer].account);

        Officer  memory newOfficer = Officer({
            firstName:firstName,
            lastName:lastName,
            account:officer
        });

        officers[officer] = newOfficer;
        numberOfOffiers++;
    }

    function getOfficer(address officer) public view returns(address){
        return officers[officer].account;
    }


}
```

I want to get the details of all officers. I searched in the net to find a solution to return details of a mapping. But I was unable to do it. Can someone help me to do this? Thank You!!

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the details of every officer saved in the officers mapping? Like return an array of everything in the Officer struct?

Comment: @vhie Yeah That what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smart contract itself does not know what has been stored in the mapping, as it does not maintain the list of set keys.

You need to create

- An additional array where you add all keys that has been set - array contains keys of the map
- Getter function that returns the length of this array, so that you can iterate through the all keys
- Getter function that allows to query array index Nth item:

Example for the last one:

```
 function getNthOfficerName(uint n) returns(string) {
    return officers[storedKeys[n]];
 }
```